# How put image in Expandable List View in different mood

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[to view sample image , please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94m5x.jpg)
I want to use expandable list view With the following codes . but I want put 2 different image in header 1 and 2 different image in header 2  , also put 3 different image in sub item 1 ans  2 different image in sub item 2 . I'm use it in eclips Android Programing

Code ExpandableListAdapter:

```js
package com.expand.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
  
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
  
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
  
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
  
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }
  
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }
  
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }
  
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
  
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
  
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
  
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }
  
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }
  
    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }
  
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }
  
    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }
  
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
  
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
  
        return convertView;
    }
  
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
  
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity Code :

```js
package com.expand.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter         listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView            expListView;
    List<String>                  listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }


    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Test1");
        listDataHeader.add("Test2");
        listDataHeader.add("Test3");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("SubItem1");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("SubItem1 ");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("SubItem1 ");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >
  
            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:divider="@null"/>  
  
</LinearLayout>
```

list_itme:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" android:textColor="#000000"/>
  
</LinearLayout>
```

list_group.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#000000">
  
  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please explain clearly.

Comment: I have listDataHeader and listChildHeader . in DataHeder I have TextView and Indicator so I want to put image in first dataheader that this image dont show in other dataHeader . sub itmem as well as dataheader.

Comment: somebody can help me ?